# MySQL PHP - SELECT WHERE id = array()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one table with following fields...

```
   id category_id product_id
    1     1         1001
    2     2         1001
    3     1         1003
    4     4         1001
    5     1         1005
```

Now i'm trying to fetch out product id using category id.

So suppose in my query string i pass www.demo.com/?category=1,2,4

I want to get product which match in all value(1,2,4). so in this case it should return me only 1001.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use IN() in combination with GROUP BY and HAVING

```
SELECT
    product_id
FROM 
    your table
WHERE
    category_id IN (1, 2, 4)
GROUP BY
    product_id
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT id) = 3;
```

**Explanation**

With COUNT (DISTINCT id) =  you check that this product_id will be in every category you checked.

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/593d34/1)**

Answer (score 5):

Use [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE category_id IN(1,2,4);
```

Comment: This will not return just 1001 (as OP wants), but 1003 and 1005 too

Answer (score 1):

Generally I would go with the solution above by VMai, but just to give you another option you can join the table against itself, one for each possible category_id:-

```
SELECT a.product_id
FROM table a 
INNER JOIN table b ON a.product_id = b.product_id
INNER JOIN table c ON b.product_id = c.product_id
WHERE a.category = 1
AND b.category = 2
AND c.category = 4
```

Comment: This will produce the desired results too. The main drawback of the multiple self join is that it's not as easy to create dynamically. I won't speculate about the performance of both approaches with big tables and longer lists.

Comment: I fully agree with your comment. It is possibly easier to understand but its main advantage is if a few other columns details were required and which could not be used in the GROUP BY. Performance issues would be massively influenced by indexes.